# SharePoint 2013- list template

Tags: list, template

I am trying to move a list from one SP 2013 site to another site.
I created a list template and included content, downloaded the file (.stp) and uploaded the file to the new site template gallery. I then created an app using that list template file I uploaded on the new site,  but when I view this list app I created I see this message: List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

However, when I go to the new site, site settings,  content and structure and open that list I do see all the items that were  on the list.

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds* like your List 'A' might have a lookup column to List 'B'.  Have you copied both lists and content to the new site?